# Laravel relationship values execute in controller

Tags: laravel-5.1

I called a table with relationship in controller.

I want to print the relationship values in controller.

Here I have given below the sample:

```
TestItem::where('test_id', $testId)->with('testresults')->get();
```

How can I print the values of `testresults` in controller?

Comment: If you want to show the content of `TestItem....etc` just pass it as `$variable` and one way to go is using `dd($variable);`

Answer (score 0):

You create an object of result then print that object using php function like **`print_r(array)`** and exit flow using `exit()`;

```
$TestItem = TestItem::where('test_id', $testId)->with('testresults')->get();
print_r($TestItem);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to print a relationship values.
For example with(testresults) is there, i want to print that values in controller.
Not the TestItem table values.